# Populating geom using lat/long or x/y

Tags: postgis, postgresql, geometry, latitude-longitude, xy

I'm having trouble populating a geometry (geom) column by using already existing columns (the data has an x, y, as well as lat, long columns) the 4 columns are in varchar. I have created the geometry column (set to 4326 same as the table I'll be comparing it to) however all 112 rows are null. I had already tried:

```
UPDATE gas_stations 
SET geom = ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(longitude, latitude), 4326);
```

Code above found on StackExchange

Comment: What do you mean by "null" ? Also, please, post the result of `SELECT longitude, latitude FROM your_table ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 4;

Comment: Null as in it returns all 122 rows as null (like all the rows in the geom column return "Null". Results are:                                                                                       
-77.02610456 38.98222912
-77.02592104 38.979662
-77.01907675 38.97503886
-77.02705218 38.9681158
-77.02685856 38.96753185 (longitude, latitude)

Answer (score 5):

This SQL snippet should work on PG 15 + PostGIS 3.3:

```
--DROP TABLE public.temp;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS public.temp
(
    id bigint PRIMARY KEY GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY,
    longitude numeric,
    latitude numeric,
    geom geometry(Point,4326)
);

INSERT INTO public.temp(longitude, latitude) VALUES
  (0,36),(4, 37),(8, 38),(12, 39),(16, 40),(20, 41),(24, 42),(28, 43);


UPDATE public.temp SET geom = ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(longitude, latitude), 4326);

SELECT * FROM public.temp;
```

=>

[image]

So you probably need to convert your `varchar` column to real numbers, because `ST_MakePoint()` is only accepting numbers, not text, per the [doc](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_MakePoint.html):

> Synopsis
>
> geometry ST_MakePoint(float x, float y);
>
> geometry ST_MakePoint(float x, float y, float z);
>
> geometry ST_MakePoint(float x, float y, float z, float m);

Hence:

```
DROP TABLE public.temp;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS public.temp
(
    "id" bigint PRIMARY KEY GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY,
    longitude varchar (20),
    latitude varchar (20),
    geom geometry(Point,4326)
);

INSERT INTO public.temp(longitude, latitude) VALUES
  (0,36), (4, 37),(8, 38),(12, 39),(16, 40),(20, 41),(24, 42),(28, 43);


UPDATE public.temp SET geom = ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(longitude, latitude), 4326);
```

will raise:

```
ERROR:  function st_makepoint(character varying, character varying) does not exist
LINE 15: UPDATE public.temp SET geom = ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(longit...
                                                  ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
SQL state: 42883
Character: 378
```

Thus, you need to "[type cast](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-tutorial/postgresql-cast/)" you varchar fields into, e.g. [numeric](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-numeric.html):

```
DROP TABLE public.temp;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS public.temp
(
    "id" bigint PRIMARY KEY GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY,
    longitude varchar (20),
    latitude varchar (20),
    geom geometry(Point,4326)
);

INSERT INTO public.temp(longitude, latitude) VALUES
  (0,36), (4, 37),(8, 38),(12, 39),(16, 40),(20, 41),(24, 42),(28, 43);


UPDATE public.temp SET geom = ST_SetSRID(
  ST_MakePoint(
    longitude::numeric,
    latitude::numeric
  ),
  4326
);

SELECT * FROM public.temp;
```

=>

[image]

[image]

Finally, this may be obvious, but you need to have [PostGIS](https://postgis.net/) installed in your database:

```
CREATE EXTENSION postgis;
CREATE EXTENSION postgis_topolgoy;
```

You can check your PostGIS version with:

```
SELECT postgis_full_version();
```